# MockMvc receive 404 when prometheus endpoint is calling

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus

I want to test Prometheus metrics endpoint using `MockMvc` class.

Everything works fine but yesterday I migrate my project to `Java 15`, `SpringBoot 2.4.3` and `SpringCloud 2020.0.1`. Now, only prometheus test not works and I receive **404** not **200** as expected. I have all the necessary dependency on `build.gradle` e.q.: `runtime("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")`. On `application-test.yml` I have a configuration for disabled security, contract tests pact broker endpoints etc.

my test:

```
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, PostgresSpringDataSourceExtension.class})
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class PrometheusEndpointTest {

 @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;

 @Test
 public void metricsThroughPrometheusEndpoint() throws Exception {
  MvcResult result = 
  this.mockMvc.perform(get("/metrics")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
 }
}
```

Part of `application.yaml` configuration:

```
management:
  endpoint:
    prometheus:
      enabled: true
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: false
    web:
      exposure:
        include: 'prometheus'
      base-path: '/'
      path-mapping:
        prometheus: 'metrics'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution: we need to add properties to the test annotation or to `application-test.yml`:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(
  webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT,
  properties = "management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled")
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one solution to add:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = ["management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true"])
```

as org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.export.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration requires it to be enabled to export